# Custom new tab in Woocommerce my account pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoints

This question is about my woocommerce shop. I am trying to add new tab in my-account page (ticket tab). Eeverything going right, but when I hit the "ticket" tab I getting **"404 not found"** error!

I thought it should be work, but its no working.

Here is changes log:

add ticket code to woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_account_ticket' ) ) {

    /**
     * My Account > Ticket template.
     */
    function woocommerce_account_ticket() {
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/ticket.php' );
    }
}
```

add ticket code to woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_account_ticket_endpoint', 'woocommerce_account_ticket' );
```

add ticket code to woocommerce/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-accounts.php

```
array(
    'title'    => __( 'Ticket', 'woocommerce' ),
    'desc'     => __( 'Endpoint for the "My account &rarr;     ticket" page.', 'woocommerce' ),
    'id'       => 'woocommerce_myaccount_ticket_endpoint',
    'type'     => 'text',
    'default'  => 'ticket',
    'desc_tip' => true,
),
```

add ticket code to woocommerce/includes/wc-account-functions.php

```
function wc_get_account_menu_items() {
    $endpoints = array(
        'ticket'       => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_ticket_endpoint', 'ticket' ),
    );

    $items = array(
        'ticket'          => __( 'Ticket', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
```

add ticket code to woocommerce/includes/class-wc-query.php

```
'ticket'                  => get_option(     'woocommerce_myaccount_ticket_endpoint', 'ticket' ),
```

I don't want to update my woocommerce plugin, so there is no problem about playing with main plugin codes.

Comment: May be you need to flush rewrite rules in WP … Go to Setting > Permalinks and hit "save" at the end of the page… This will refresh the responsible rules for end points.

Comment: Awesome, working like a charm man!

Comment: So the answer here was:  flush the WP rewrite rules (saving permalinks in WP settings)… Happy it worked for you.